# Combine objects in an array and add values. JavaScript / node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

is there a way to turn

```
[ { JavaScript: 41837, Batchfile: 47 },
  { 'C#': 7484 },
  { Batchfile: 110 },
  { Scala: 50597 },
  { Java: 18180 },
  { Java: 55689 } ]
```

into:

```
{ 
JavaScript: 41837,
Batchfile: 157,
'C#': 7484
Scala: 50597,
Java: 73869
}
```

The size of the array is different every time we run the application.

Comment: Are the values always numbers to sum?

Answer (score 3):

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is your friend

```js
const list = [ { JavaScript: 41837, Batchfile: 47 },
  { 'C#': 7484 },
  { Batchfile: 110 },
  { Scala: 50597 },
  { Java: 18180 },
  { Java: 55689 } ];
const summed = list.reduce((totals, obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
    const cur = totals[k] || 0;
    totals[k] = cur + obj[k];
  });
  return totals;
}, {});
   console.log(summed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new object. Iterate through each object in the input array. For each object, iterate through the keys of that object. If they key exists in your new object, add the value, otherwise add the key and value to the new object;

```js
var arr = [ { JavaScript: 41837, Batchfile: 47 },
  { 'C#': 7484 },
  { Batchfile: 110 },
  { Scala: 50597 },
  { Java: 18180 },
  { Java: 55689 } ]
  
var result = {}

arr.forEach(function(group){
  Object.keys(group).forEach(function(key){
    if(result[key]) {
      result[key] += group[key];
    } else {
      result[key] = group[key];
    }
  })
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array reduce in combination with For in to loop through the object keys in them would get what you want.

```
a = [ { JavaScript: 41837, Batchfile: 47 },
  { 'C#': 7484 },
  { Batchfile: 110 },
  { Scala: 50597 },
  { Java: 18180 },
  { Java: 55689 } ]

  result = {}

  b = a.reduce((result, item) => {
    for (let eachKey in item) {
      const curSum = result[eachKey] || 0;;
      result[eachKey] = curSum + item[eachKey];
    }
    return result;
  }, result)
```